# Wallet for digital goods : TVA and subscription frequency

Tags: android-pay

I use the wallet for digital goods for three month on production but some annoying behaviour are puzzling me.

First of all, taxes are taken into account for the "initialPayment" but not for the "recurrence" one. This is very anoying since I don't have API to let the server now what clients do actualy pay.

Secondly, it seems that the monthly frequency is 30 days regardless of the month. This is also very annoying since the billing date in the month shifts gradually.

Is it possible I missed something in the configuration of the JWT to have that kind of behavior ?

Thx